# Netbeans 7.3.1 FTP downloading issue on Mac ("I won't open connection to" error..."

Tags: netbeans, ftp

I've set up a new PHP project on NetBeans, configured the FTP manager to open a standard (pure) FTP connection to my host...'Test Connection' works successfully ... FileZilla
works fine to log in to host + open + edit files (normal FTP operations).

Just can't get it to download my files in Netbeans ... very frustrating

> USER hicksads 331 User hicksads OK. Password required PASS ****** 230
>   OK. Current restricted directory is / PBSZ 0 200 PBSZ=0 TYPE I 200
>   TYPE is now 8-bit binary CWD /public_html 250 OK. Current directory is
>   /public_html PWD 257 "/public_html" is your current location CWD
>   /public_html 250 OK. Current directory is /public_html PWD 257
>   "/public_html" is your current location SYST 215 UNIX Type: L8 PORT
>   192,168,100,18,194,238 
>   500 I won't open a connection to 192.168.100.18 (only to 110.142.50.242) 
>   QUIT 221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and
>   downloaded 0 kbytes. 221 Logout.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I've checked with our IT, there's no local firewall apparently. I've google it, the only thing that people have suggested is using Passive FTP mode - I can't see where that is set in NB? The only options in the FTP conn manager are Pure FTP, Implicit using TLS, Explicit using TLS (I've tried all of them, all give same error).

Comment: Nevermind, resolved. Passive mode checkbox is quite hidden on mac Netbeans.

Comment: thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

I was in a hotel room and needed to download all the files for a project.

When downloading with netbeans on a pc...

I wont open a connection to ip address only to ip address...

after some searching it was this post that helped me.

```
1. find the remote connection row and click manage

2. most ftp accounts will need port 2

3. at the bottom there is a check box for passive mode. Check it.
```

test connection and if succesfull you are ready to download.